# Polymer 1.0: Installing Polymer Starter Kit from command line throws error

Tags: bash, polymer, polymer-1.0, yeoman-generator, polymer-starter-kit

> **How do I fix this so I can install the Polymer Starter Kit?**

The command:

```
$ yo polymer
```

throws the following error:

```
readline.js:924
                        throw err;
                        ^

Error: Cannot find module 'yeoman-environment'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
        at require (module.js:385:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-polymer/node_modules/yeoman-generator/index.js:7:19)
        at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
        at require (module.js:385:17)
```

#### Version Configuration

- MacBook Air
- OS X v.10.10.5 Yosemite

Toolchain:

```
$ node -v
v5.1.1

$ npm -v
3.5.1

$ yo --version
1.5.0

$ bower --version
1.6.9

$ grunt --version
grunt-cli v0.1.13

$ gulp --version
CLI version 3.9.0
```

Comment: That's a bug with npm. You should open an issue on their side. Also update to latest npm and retry. It'll probably work eventually if you re-install from a clean state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the Yeoman Polymer-generator globally.

```
$ cd
$ sudo npm install --global generator-polymer
# or
$ sudo npm install -g generator-polymer
```

Then install Yeoman Polymer-generator in project directory.

```
$ cd path/to/project
$ sudo npm install --global generator-polymer
# or
$ sudo npm install -g generator-polymer
```